Requiring a subdirectory to access a webpage service using apache2 and a dynamic DNS
I'm trying to disallow the basic 80 HTTP server to be at the root of my dynamic DNS, but instead use a subdirectory.
so instead of
blabla.dynamicdns.org
it won't be served
but at
blabla.dynamicdns.org/service it would be.
This configuration attempt did not work. Says document roots are not allowed in Directory tags.
I know how much SE loves its examples, I'm dumping this otherwise vanilla config here anyway.
I literally know nothing and I literally need to be spoon-fed here and it's a pill to Google for this.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost


    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    <Directory /var/www/html/ampache/>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ampache
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ampache/public
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

A more correct config, that still does not yield my desired result:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ampache
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ampache/public

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

Sorry for this de facto spam, but my history with SE and lust for "working examples" on topics I don't even know how they work, has forced my hand.

The first error is exactly that. Certain directives, including the DocumentRoot are not allowed in a Directory block. In addition multiple DocumentRoot directives don’t make sense either, you should have one.

Yeah, I know, it's not working, but had I not posted anything then I would have been told to provided a minimal working example. But have you ever tried writing a sentence with words you don't know? Try it, try writing a sentence with words you do not actually know. Not ...words you don't know the meaning of, but words you never heard about before in your life. Not that easy is it?  That's my problem here. I don't know what to do and googling was not successful. Surely this is an easy problem to solve, I just can't seearch for it on an automatic websearch, need a human who knows it to tell me.

Read the documentation on how to configure Apache. Apache has extensive documentation. Or pay someone to administer the solution.


read the manual or pay someone to help you

Does that not fit every question on SE? Guess the website can be closed and server costs and co can be saved! Eureka!

DocumentRoot always defines the mapping of / (the root directory of your URLs). To define mappings for URL subdirectories, instead use Alias. See Mapping URLs for a general overview.
Alias /ampache /var/www/html/ampache/public

(Roughly speaking, DocumentRoot /var/foo is like Alias "/" /var/foo.)
If you don't want to serve anything at /, map DocumentRoot to an empty directory (possibly even one with restricted permissions) and use Alias to define the individual sub­directories you want.
It doesn't make sense to have more than one DocumentRoot per vhost, as they all would define mappings for the same / and a URL can only go to one location at a time – only the last definition will be used. Likewise it doesn't make sense to Alias the same path more than once.

Thanks for actually spelling out the part that's relevant and linking to the docs. Someone suggested I should have just done so in the first place, but again, it's difficult to look for something if you don't know the terminology.
